# JS: How to set up a closure within an event listener?

Tags: javascript

I've been reading a lot about closures but still am having a hard time grasping them. I'm trying to get a parallax scrolling function to work by adding a dynamically determined number of pixels to an element's `top` style attribute every time the user scrolls.

```
var parallaxApp = {

    publicVars = {},

    addListeners: function() {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", parallaxApp.setHeight, false);
        //more listeners would go here
    },

    //this function is invoked every time the user scrolls
    setHeight: function() {            
        var height = parallaxApp.publicVars["set height"]; //34

        //every time setHeight is invoked I want to add 34
        return function() {

            //how can I store this local variable outside of the execution of its scope?
            height = height + parallaxApp.publicVars["set height"]; //34, 68, 102, etc.
            document.getElementById("someDiv").style.top = height+"px";
        } 
    },

    run: function() {  

        //set public variables
        for (var arg in arguments[0]) {
            parallaxApp.publicVars[arg] = arguments[0][arg];
        }

        //once the page loads, attach various listeners to the window object
        window.addEventListener("load", parallaxApp.addListeners, false);
    }

}

parallaxApp.run({"set height": 34});
```

Because I'm invoking a function on every scroll that's instantiated through an event listener, I'm confused as to how I should be setting up my scopes. Is the only way to do this by modifying the `publicVars` "public" variable on every invocation of `setHeight`? (also no jquery please)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `setHeight` is returning the actual scroll event handler you need to invoke the `setHeight` function so that the function returned by it will be set as the handler

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", parallaxApp.setHeight(), false);
```

Also you should not modify the closure variable `height`

```
setHeight: function() {            
    var height = parallaxApp.publicVars["set height"]; //34

    //every time setHeight is invoked I want to add 34
    return function() {

        //how can I store this local variable outside of the execution of its scope?
        var xheight = height + parallaxApp.publicVars["set height"]; //34, 68, 102, etc.
        document.getElementById("someDiv").style.top = xheight +"px";
    } 
}
```